# MySQL - 2 foreign keys

Tags: mysql, count, foreign-keys

I'm working on a league table for baseball. Let's say I got the following 2 DB tables:

**teams**

```
ID  | NAME
---------------------------
1   | Phillies
2   | Yankees
3   | Red Sox
```

**games**

```
ID | TEAM1_ID | TEAM2_ID | TEAM1_SCORE | TEAM2_SCORE
----------------------------------------------------
1  | 2        | 1        | 12          |  8
2  | 3        | 2        |  9          | 14
3  | 1        | 2        | 10          |  5
```

I would like MySQL to give me a list of all the teams and their results. That includes total games played, won and lost games.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

For example, the resultset may look like this:

```
team_name | total_played | total_won | total_lost
-------------------------------------------------
Phillies  | 2            | 1         | 1
Yankees   | 3            | 2         | 1
Red Sox   | 1            | 0         | 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably same as sgeddes solution. 
I put the conditionals in a subquery so I could test the inner results first

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/98c3c/9)**

```
SELECT t.`NAME`, 
       SUM(play) as total, 
       SUM(WON) as games_won, 
       SUM(LOST) as games_lost,
       SUM(SCORE) as total_score
FROM (
      SELECT t.`NAME`,
             IF(g.`TEAM1_ID`IS NULL, 0, 1) as play,
             CASE WHEN t.`ID` = g.`TEAM1_ID` AND TEAM1_SCORE > TEAM2_SCORE THEN 1
                  WHEN t.`ID` = g.`TEAM2_ID` AND TEAM1_SCORE < TEAM2_SCORE THEN 1 
                  ELSE 0
             END as WON,
             CASE WHEN t.`ID` = g.`TEAM1_ID` AND TEAM1_SCORE < TEAM2_SCORE THEN 1
                  WHEN t.`ID` = g.`TEAM2_ID` AND TEAM1_SCORE > TEAM2_SCORE THEN 1 
                  ELSE 0
             END as LOST,
             CASE WHEN t.`ID` = g.`TEAM1_ID` THEN TEAM1_SCORE
                  WHEN t.`ID` = g.`TEAM2_ID` THEN TEAM2_SCORE
                  ELSE 0
             END as SCORE                         
      FROM teams t
      LEFT JOIN games g
        ON t.`ID` = g.`TEAM1_ID`
        OR t.`ID` = g.`TEAM2_ID`
   ) T
GROUP BY t.`NAME`
```

**OUTPUT**

```
|     NAME | total | games_won | games_lost | total_score |
|----------|-------|-----------|------------|-------------|
| Phillies |     2 |         1 |          1 |          18 |
|  Red Sox |     1 |         0 |          1 |           9 |
|     Some |     0 |         0 |          0 |           0 |
|  Yankees |     3 |         2 |          1 |          31 |
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Is there any way to add an extra coumn to the output table that accumulates all the team scores? E.g. Team Phillies would have a value of 18 (8 + 10)..

Comment: This is close to my solution.  The only issue is if a team has not played, this will return an incorrect total count: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7089b2/1

Comment: @sgeddes Did you include that comment after I update with `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: @elton73 As you request, I Include the total_score.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza -- Using the `outer join` won't help (see fiddle posted in my comment).  It's because you are counting from a subquery which is flattened -- so all records have at least 1 count.  My `outer join` counts only on the field from the `games` table which results in 0 if null.  Nice approach though if this isn't a concern.  To resolve, you could add `g.id` to your subquery and `count` on it -- I think that would be the same as what I'm doing.

Comment: @sgeddes Ok, Is fixed now. Your approach is better and simpler. Mine only good if you want test the internal result first.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Thanks for adding the 'total_score' column to the resultset. Very nice approach :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option using `conditional aggregation`:

```
select t.name, 
  count(g.id) total_played,
  sum(case when (t.id = team1_id and team1_score > team2_score) then 1
           when (t.id = team2_id and team2_score > team1_score) then 1 
           else 0
      end) total_won,
  sum(case when (t.id = team1_id and team1_score < team2_score) then 1
           when (t.id = team2_id and team2_score < team1_score) then 1 
           else 0
      end) total_lost
 from teams t
   left join games g on t.id in (g.team1_id, g.team2_id)
 group by t.name
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5a451/1)

Comment: Works well in the fiddle. I'm gonna give this a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT t.name,count(*) as TotalPlayed,
       count(case when s.team1_score > s.team2_score then 1 end) as total_won,
       count(case when s.team2_score > s.team1_score then 1 end) as total_lose
FROM teams t
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT Team1_ID,Team1_score,Team2_Score FROM games 
            UNION ALL
            SELECT Team2_ID,Team2_Score,Team1_Score FROM games) s
 ON(t.id = s.team1_id)
GROUP BY t.name
```

This will basically make the games table more comfortable to work with, multiply the record for each team so the counts will be easy and won't have to check multiple conditions.

Comment: I can confirm this works. Just removed the typo in line 3 (should be no comma after "as total_lose"). Thanks!

Comment: No problem, would appreciate an approval if it helped you:) And yea you are right, fixed the typo. @elton73

Comment: The problem with this one is if a Team hasnt play yet, wont appear with `TotalPlayed = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
 select id, name,
 (select count(*) from games where team1_id = id OR team2_id = id) as total_played,
 (select count(*) from games where (team1_id = id and team1_score > team2_score) OR (team2_id = id and team1_score < team2_score)) as total_won,
 (select count(*) from games where (team1_id = id and team1_score < team2_score) OR (team2_id = id and team1_score > team2_score)) as total_lost
from teams
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d27a/4/0) is the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Won't work.. you are only looking at team1_id , and not on team2_id.

Comment: Correct. Tested it but it only looks at the team1_id column.

Comment: @elton73 did you try my query? should work fine for you.

Comment: @Darshan Mehta Your answer is nice and simple, but that query uses the game id in the WHERE clauses. It should be replaced by the team id. I created a working fiddle with that modification: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d27a/5

Comment: Sorry, don't know what is changed.. :)

Comment: Your WHERE clause: "team1_id = id OR team2_id = id". Replaced by: "team1_id = t.id OR team2_id = t.id". It's now referring to team id instead of games id.